Ample representation of a $C^*$-algebra
Let $A$ be a separable $C^*$-algebra. Does there always exist a representation $\rho:A\to B(H)$ on a separable Hilbert space $H$ such that

$\rho$ is non-degenerate (i.e. $\rho(A)H$ is dense in $H$)
if $a\neq 0$ then $\rho(a)$ is not compact

I know we can always find one satisfying 1. via the Gelfand–Naimark representation. However, I am not sure if 2. can always be satisfied.
The authors Higson and Roe in the book Analytic K-homology called such representation an ample representation (def 5.1.3).

Since $A$ is separable, there exists a faithful non-degenerate representation $\pi: A \to B(K)$ on some separable Hilbert space $K$. Then $\rho = \pi \otimes 1_{\ell^2}$, i.e., $\rho: A \to B(K \otimes \ell^2)$, $\rho(a) = \pi(a) \otimes 1_{\ell^2}$, is ample.

Thank you for your answer. However, I am not very familiar with tensor product. Could you say more about your $\rho$?

@CatBranchman If you’re not familiar with tensor products, just think of this as taking the direct sum of countably infinite many copies of $\pi$, i.e., $\rho: A \to B(\oplus_{n=1}^\infty K)$, $\rho(a) = \oplus_{n=1}^\infty \pi(a)$. It’s the same thing.

Thanks. So the representation is ample since for operator on $\oplus_{n=1}^\infty K$ to be compact, its norm must decay to zero (going diagonally into infinity). Thus $\rho(a)$ cannot be compact.

@CatBranchman Indeed, yes. $\rho(a)$ cannot be compact unless $\pi(a) = 0$. Since $\pi$ is assumed faithful, this only happens when $a = 0$.

@CatBranchman The general fact is that, if, for each $i\in I$, $\pi_i:A\to B(K_i)$ is non-degenerate, then the direct sum representation $\pi:A\to B(H)$ where $H=\oplus_{i\in I}K_i$, $\pi(a)=\oplus_{i\in I}\pi_i(a)$ is non-degenerate. Indeed, each $K_i$ is a subspace of $H$, and $\pi(a)k_i=\pi_i(a)k_i$ for any $k_i\in K_i$. Thus, $\pi(A)K_i=\pi_i(A)K_i$ is dense in $K_i$ for all $i$, as $\pi_i$ is non-degenerate. Hence, as $\pi(A)H$ contains $\pi(A)K_i$ for all $i$, the closure of $\pi(A)H$ contains all $K_i$. $K_i$ for all $i$ densely span $H$, so the closure of $\pi(A)H$ is $H$.

Very well! I keep forgetting that span of $\pi(A)H$ dense in $H$ implies that $\pi(A)H$ is dense in $H$. Somehow the latter seems stronger.

@CatBranchman Ah, usually in the definition I’m familiar with, $\pi(A)H$ is defined to mean the span, not just the set of all $\pi(a)h$, so that’s what I assumed. But yeah, as far as non-degeneracy goes, it doesn’t matter which version to use, they are equivalent because $C^\ast$-algebras have approximate identities.
