Property of an ample representation of a $C^*$-algebra
Let $A$ be a separable $C^*$-algebra. We say that a representation $\rho:A\to B(H)$ is ample if

$\rho$ is non-degenerate (i.e. $\rho(A)H$ is dense in $H$)
if $a\neq 0$ then $\rho(a)$ is not compact

Let $A$ be amply represented by $\rho$, and $T\in B(H)$. Show that if $\rho(a)T$ is compact for all $a\in A$, then $T$ is compact.
If $\rho$ is non-degenerate, then based on property 6 of this, I can show that if $\rho(a)T=0$ for all $a$, then $T=0$. However, I am not sure if this idea works for the above claim.

This is not true. Let $\rho$ be the standard representation of $K(\ell^2)$ repeated infinitely many times, i.e., $\rho(x) = \bigoplus_{n=1}^\infty x$ acting on $\bigoplus_{n=1}^\infty \ell^2$. This is ample. But $T = 1_{\ell^2} \oplus (\bigoplus_{n=2}^\infty 0)$ satisfies $\rho(x)T$ is compact for all $x \in K(\ell^2)$, but $T$ is not compact.

Could you elaborate on why $\rho(x)=\bigoplus_{n=1}^\infty x$ is  a non-degenerate representation on $B(\bigoplus_{n=1}^\infty \ell^2)$?

@CatBranchman I’ve replied to you in your previous question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4986371/ample-representation-of-a-c-algebra, since that is the more general case. This is just a specific example of that.
